# Fancybox add attribute to video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to display videos with popups on my website, the problem is that on Chrome there is bug or whatever that it the video seems to be stocked, doesn't happens on other browsers.

The way to solve is to add `preload="none"` into iframe video.
manually it's not a problem, the thing is that it's been created dynamically and I cant get into that attributes.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
    $.fancybox({
        href: this.href,
        type: "iframe",
        iframe : {
            preload: false,
            autoplay:false
        }
    }); // fancybox
    return false
}); // on
```

Smaller videos works good, So it's for sure seems to be preload problem.

Comment: what type of videos? what the is the (dynamically) rendered html?

Comment: video type is MP4, <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="http://restartit.co.il/prod/sites/lrg/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video> , cant edit it as code.. weird, anyway, thats rendered dynamically!. thanks

Comment: You may want to check [this tutorial](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/) ... I actually covered an issue with webkit browsers

Comment: Well, I was actually was looking for a solution that wont be in need of more plugins, but if that's the only way.
I will go on that path probably. Thanks.